# Ideas needed on expanding Jira DB to include multiple target platforms

Tags: agile, jira, bugs

So first I'll explain my position. I am a member on the QA team but tasked with majority of the management of the Jira instance. We have launched our product on one platform, and will be starting to develop it shortly on two more platforms. I am primarily concerned with just the bugs on the database for this reason. Tasks etc., are used elsewhere and I only really change those upon request.

It has already been decided that we will be sticking with just the one project on Jira for this, for various reasons (some things out of my control etc).

We already have a "platforms" field, where we have a select box for each platform, and this has been used consistently for all bugs so far. I have all my filters, dashboards etc set up to include / filter out the platforms as I require, so all of that is ready to go.

The main thing I am thinking about right now, is our bug creation process and our bug regression process.

We regress our bugs at a semi-regular interval, and is often the fallback "if you don't have anything else to do, hit that regression list!".

What we will be having, is a process whereby when a bug is created, the creator marks the bug with the platform it was found in. This will be, for arguments sake, platform 1. This bug should show up somewhere that it now needs to be checked in platforms 2 and 3. It should be checked there and then not show up in the lists once checked (whether it effects them or not). We have multiple criteria for bugs entering our regression list at present... it depends partly on its priority, and whether it has been regressed in this build already or not.

When a bug is regressed, a field is updated with the current date to show it was regressed today. I now need all bugs to be regressed on each platform each time. But if I dont make any changes, then it will show up in all 3 regression lists until it is regressed in one platform, then it will disappear from all lists. What I need is for it to only disappear from the platform field it was regressed in...

How would you go about tackling this? There are multiple ways but want to be pointed in the "better" direction. :)

(Side Note: We are using ondemand instance, so can only use plugins which work here).

Comment: Is this a project management question? What is the project management problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create an agile board to do this you could have the following columns:

New Bug -> tested on other platforms -> In Development  -> In QA  -> Fixed/Done